# Include Gradle sourceSet in project output so it can be resolved as dependency in other projects

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm developing a Gradle plugin that creates additional sourceSets and sets up relations between them to create sort of hierarchy. When working with a single project using this plugin everything works, but now I'm in a situation, where I need a multi-project build, where all subprojects use the plugin.

When I add `implementation(project(":subproject"))` then the only references that are discovered by IDE are the ones coming from the `main` sourceSet. How can I configure my dependency to point to more sourceSets than `main` or to any other besides the `main` one?

sourceSets and configurations setup done by the plugin is described by this code:

```kotlin
private fun Project.setupSourceSets(portName: String, domainName: String, adapterName: String) {
        with(project.extensions.getByType(JavaPluginExtension::class.java)) {
            sourceSets.run {
                val domain = create(domainName) {
                    it.java.srcDir(listOf("src/$domainName/$portName/java"))

                    if (plugins.hasPlugin("kotlin")) {
                        it.java.srcDirs("src/$domainName/$portName/kotlin")
                    }
                }

                val adapter = create(adapterName) {
                    it.runtimeClasspath += domain.output
                    it.compileClasspath += domain.output
                }

                getByName("main") {
                    it.runtimeClasspath += domain.output
                    it.compileClasspath += domain.output

                    it.runtimeClasspath += adapter.output
                    it.compileClasspath += adapter.output

                    it.output.dir(adapter.output)
                    it.output.dir(domain.output)
                }

                getByName("test") {
                    it.runtimeClasspath += domain.output
                    it.compileClasspath += domain.output

                    it.runtimeClasspath += adapter.output
                    it.compileClasspath += adapter.output
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun Project.setupConfigurations(domainName: String, adapterName: String) {
        configurations.run {
            val implementation = getByName("implementation")

            val domainImplementation = getByName("${domainName}Implementation") {
                it.isCanBeConsumed = true
                it.isCanBeResolved = true
                it.extendsFrom(implementation)
            }

            getByName("${adapterName}Implementation") {
                it.isCanBeConsumed = true
                it.isCanBeResolved = true
                it.extendsFrom(implementation, domainImplementation)
            }
        }
    }
```